# Estimating a power series for the order of an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, estimation

Let $0<s<1$ and consider the power series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{r^n}{(n!)^{1/s}}.$$ I need to show that for any given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $R>0$ such that for all $r>R$, $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{r^n}{(n!)^{1/s}}<\exp({r^{s+\epsilon}}).$$

This comes from a complex analysis problem, where I need to prove that the entire function $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{(n!)^{1/s}}$ has order at most $s$, which, in this context, translates to the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can show that the order $\rho$ of an entire function $f$ can be computed as
$$
\rho = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{n\log n}{\log(1/|a_n|)}
$$
where $a_n$ are the Maclaurin coefficients of $f$.

In your case, you have $a_n = \dfrac{1}{(n!)^{1/s}}$, so
$$
\rho = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{s\, n\log n}{\log(n!)} = s
$$
(using some standard estimates of $n!$).

Comment: Thanks a lot! In fact I have been trying to prove the more general fact that you just stated: the order of $f$ equals $\alpha:=\limsup_n (n\log n)/\log(1/|a_n|)$. I have an estimate that for any $\epsilon>0$, $|a_n|\le n^{-n/(\alpha+\epsilon)}$ if $n$ is sufficiently large. But I could not estimate $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|r^n$ when $\alpha<1$. Do you have a reference to this result?

Comment: That result should be almost any textbook that talks about the order of entire functions. One of the standard references would be "Entire functions" by Boas.